# Moving marker along path/polyline using Leaflet API?

Tags: leaflet

Trying to migrate from Googlemaps to Leaflet, some errors return in following functions.

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
//
Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
  return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}
// polyline length calc
L.Polyline.prototype.m_len = function () {
  var distance = 0,  coords = null, coordsArray = this._latlngs;
  for (i = 0; i < coordsArray.length - 1; i++) {
    coords = coordsArray[i];
    distance += coords.distanceTo(coordsArray[i + 1]);
  }
  return distance;
}
//
function moveAlongPath(point, distance, index) {
  index = index || 0; // Set index to 0 by default.
  if (index < routePoints.length) {
    var poly = new L.Polyline([routePoints[index], routePoints[index + 1]]);
    // alert(JSON.stringify(poly, null, 4));
    var distanceToNextPoint = poly.m_len();
    if (distance <= distanceToNextPoint) {
      return routePoints[index].moveTowards(routePoints[index + 1], distance);
      // error: routePoints[index].moveTowards is not a function
    } else {
      var d_distance = distance - distanceToNextPoint;
      return moveAlongPath(routePoints, d_distance, (index + 1)); 
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} // end moveAlongPath
/////////////////////////////////
L.LatLng.prototype.moveTowards = function(point, distance) {
  var lat1 = this.lat.toRad();
  var lon1 = this.lng.toRad();
  var lat2 = point.lat().toRad();
  var lon2 = point.lng().toRad();
  var dLon = (point.lng() - this.lng()).toRad();
  // Find the bearing from this point to the next.
  var brng = Math.atan2(Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2),
                        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) -
                        Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
                        Math.cos(dLon));
  var angDist = distance / 6371000 ; // 66371000 Earth's radius.
  // Calculate the destination point, given the source and bearing.
  lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(angDist) +
                   Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(angDist) *
                   Math.cos(brng));
  lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(angDist) *
                           Math.cos(lat1),
                           Math.cos(angDist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                           Math.sin(lat2));
  if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) {return null; }
  return L.LatLng(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
} // end moveTowards
// LINESTRING COORDINATES KML FILE 
var routePoints  = <?php echo $coordstring;?>
var polycolor    = <?php echo $race_polyclr;?>
var stroke_w = 5;
var polyline = L.polyline(routePoints, {color: polycolor, weight: stroke_w});
map.addLayer(polyline)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're migrating from GMaps to Leaflet, then you should check the [Leaflet plugin list](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) before implementing any behaviour not included in the default Leaflet build.

In your particular case, you should try using [Leaflet.AnimatedMarker](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker) instead of implementing your own animation routines. Let me quote from the README file of that plugin:

```
var line = L.polyline([[40.68510, -73.94136],[40.68576, -73.94149],[40.68649, -73.94165]]),
    animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs());

map.addLayer(animatedMarker);
```